# How to rename different level entries of deeply nested JSON data into a single name so the values populate the same renamed column

Tags: pandas, json

I am trying to flatten a deeply nested JSON data and converting it into a csv using Pandas dataframe. I am able to do this but I am getting column names as entry_0_resource_code_coding_0_code, entry_1_resource_code_coding_0_code, entry_2_resource_code_coding_0_code and so on because of deeply nested JSON file and these numbers indicate different levels of data.. I want these multiple entries in a single column named as resource_code_coding and all the corresponding values of different entry level to populate this single column. I don't want to have these 'entry_0' or 'entry_1' in the beginning and '0_code' in the end of my column names. I have to append multiple files into same CSV which contains tons of data into same column but for different id's and file. So multiple entries doesn't work for me. I cannot rename every single entry separately as different files have different number and level of codes. I am using recursion for flattening the JSON data. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd


def flatten_json(nested_json: dict, exclude: list=[''], sep: str='_') -> dict:
    """
    Flatten a list of nested dicts using recursion.
    """
    out = dict()
    def flatten(x: (list, dict, str), name: str='', exclude=exclude):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                if a not in exclude:
                    flatten(x[a], f'{name}{a}{sep}')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, f'{name}{i}{sep}')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(nested_json)
    return out


# list of files
files = ['data1.json', "data4.json"]

# list to add dataframe from each file
df_list = list()

# iterate through files
for file in files:
    with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        # read with json
        data = json.loads(f.read())

        # flatten_json into a dataframe and add to the dataframe list
        data_o = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(flatten_json(data), orient='index')
        #print(data_o)

        df_list.append(data_o.T)


# concat all dataframes together
df = pd.concat(df_list).reset_index(drop=True)

df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: please post a json sample and desired output

Comment: This is my code. I cant share the JSON file and output because of security issues. But you can use it on any deeply nested JSON file.

Comment: This is my code. I cant share the JSON file and output because of security issues. But you can use it on any deeply nested JSON file. The output results in column names as levels...entry_0_resource_code_0, entry_1_resource_code_0 and so on. I dont want these entry_0 or entry_1 levels. Instead I want all the values for resource_code in the same column even if at any nested level. Hope you understand my question and can help me.